# How can this lambda variable be null?

Tags: c#, linq, list, where-clause, nullreferenceexception

There is a list of items which is written to from another thread.

The items are deleted synchronously. I have the following lambda in the delete part

```
var deleteList = this.Items.Where(d => d.Id == guid).ToList();
```

Sometimes, I get a NullReferenceException for d.

How can I find out more on that?

**More information on the context**

When removing or adding, I have a simple lock lock(myLock)
In the adding part, I already check if the item is null (if (item != null) )

Having a simple (d != null) in the where clause will not prevent
the items from getting null in the first place. In my opinion the
list should already be in a "proper state".

Comment: Try: `Items.Where(d => d != null && d.Id == guid).ToList();`

Comment: I'd try go further back, why are `null` items in `this.Items` anyway?    If you changed your code such that you were sure there were no null items in the first place, you wouldn't have to add null checks.

Comment: The check for null is there when adding.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: But maybe they become `null` somewhere in _"written to from another thread"_.

Comment: Provided more information, please have a look

Comment: @MareInfinitus You need to provide more code. It's fine you telling us you have the checks in place, but if you don't show them, we can't confirm they are correct.

Comment: Checks on adding and removing have no effect when updating. `Items.Add(new object()); Items[0] = null;` Could you be doing that? Because lists really don't change all by themselves.

Comment: Has to be something like that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threading or not, a reference in a reference can always be null. If you are deleting items from the same list, you need to place a lock on the item (or collection) before you work on it.

Without multi threading:

```
var deleteList = this.Items.Where(d => d != null && d.Id == guid).ToList();
```

Lock the collection something like this (note that there a various ways to do this):

```
lock(this.Items)
{
    var deleteList = this.Items.Where(d => d != null && d.Id == guid).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I already have some locking for adding and removing the items, and do not add null items. there seems to be some leak.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check to see if d is null

```
d => d != null && d.Id.Equals(guid)
```